# inequality of ln

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to Solve the following inequality over $\mathbb{R}$

$$ \frac{Ln(x)-1}{Ln(x)+1}\leq 2.[Ln(x)]^{2} \hspace{2mm} $$

**Ln(x) is natural logarithm**

indeed,

First thing let's determine the domain D :
$D=\{x\in \mathbb{R}  \text{ such that }  x \in \mathbb{R}^{*} \text{ and } Ln(x)+1\neq 0$ }
so 
\begin{align*}
Ln(x)+1&=0\\
Ln(x)&=-1\\
&=Ln(e^{-1})\\
x&=e^{-1}
\end{align*}
Then $$D=(0,\infty)\setminus \{e^{-1}\}=(0,e^{-1})\cup(e^{-1},\infty)$$
after we determinate the Domaine D let's solve our inequality on it :
$\forall x \in D$ and let x=ln(y)

$$
{y-1\over y+1}\le 2y^2  \hspace{2mm} \forall x \in D$$

$$ 2y^3+2y^2-y+1 \geq 0 \hspace{2mm} \forall x \in D$$

until here i don't know why i should to multiply by $(y+1)^{2}$ ( how can i know that i should to multiply exactly by $(y+1)^{2}$)

Comment: What about you try the substitution : $x = e^y$ at the very beginning.

Comment: Please be consistent with $Ln$, $ln$, $log$  I think you mean the same thing with all of them.  If you write it \log you get $\log$, which is the correct type face for functions.

Comment: True, by the way $\ln$ is used for real numbers. $Ln$ as you write it is normally called the principal logarithm, used with complex numbers which I don't think is what your question is about.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:  I'm adding an update (at bottom) at the request of the OP.  Everything here in between pertains to the original form of the question, which the OP has substantially changed. **end note**

You made a mistake of some sort in obtaining the quadratic equation in $y$.  When you let $y=\ln(x)$, the inequality becomes

$${y-1\over y+1}\le 2y^2$$

If you simply clear out the denominator (without worrying about it possibly being negative), you get a *cubic*, not a quadratic:

$$0\le 2y^3+2y^2-y+1$$

However, what you should actually do is multiply both sides by $(y+1)^2$.  This gives a quartic in factored form:

$$0\le (y+1)(2y^3+2y^2-y+1)$$

The cubic turns out to have a single root, at $y\approx-1.5369737681$, so the only interval where the (quartic) inequality fails to hold is $(-1.5369737681,-1)$.  Thus the original inequality in $y$, with the $y+1$ in the denominator, holds on $(-\infty,-1.5369737681]\cup(-1,\infty)$.  The final step is to exponentiate this to a pair of intervals for $x$:  $(0,e^{-1.5369737681}]\cup(e^{-1},\infty)$.

I'm not sure how you got the quadratic you did, but that seems to be the source of your problem.

**Update**:  The reason for multiplying both sides of the inequality by $(y+1)^2$ rather than just $y+1$ is to make sure that the inequality sign stays pointing in the same direction.  When you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative number, the inequality switches directions, e.g., $2\lt3$ becomes $(-1)\cdot2\gt(-1)\cdot3$.  The factor $y+1$ is sometimes negative, but $(y+1)^2$ is always non-negative.

It might help to remember this *Cure for Inequalities*:

*Add or subtract as you like, as you will,

But times or division can lead to great ill.*

Comment: Thanks but please why i have to multiply  by $(y+1)^{2}$ ( how can i know that i should to mulply exactly by $(y+1)^{2}$)  and which inequality  do you talk about is it first or second ?

Comment: first thing that i should to do is to determine the domain of that inequality i'll update my question